# Tilestache: Not able to render data from postGIS SQL

Tags: python, json, tilestache

my tilestache.cfg is as below:

```
{
  "cache": {
        "name": "Disk",
        "path": "mnt/tile-cache/"
    }
    ,    
  "layers":
  {  
     "countries":
    {
      "provider": {
            "name": "vector", 
            "driver": "PostgreSQL",
            "parameters": 
             {
            "dbname": "test1",
            "host" : "localhost",
            "port" : "5432",
            "user": "postgres",
                        "password":"postgres",
                        "table": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries",
                         "query":"SELECT admin, ST_Y(ST_Centroid(wkb_geometry)) as lattitude FROM ne_110m_admin_0_countries;"

             }}}}}
```

I am getting error as

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache-1.51.6-py2.7.egg/TileStache/__init__.py", line 303, in requestHandler2
    print >> out, 'Known unknown!'
```

---

I am using URL as 
localhost:8080/countries/1/1/1.json

please help me with rendering tile.

Comment: You cut the actual error message off from the traceback. And you should add your relevant code.

Comment: I am just trying to render data via DB with the below request.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same issue. I think its due to their migration to python 3 being still in progress and they broke some functionality.

Comment: Titlestache is coded in Python 2.7, please use Python 2.7 and check your connection with db. It may happen, Titlestache is not able to communicate with the database.